# Bell MT fonts in ggplot and MacOS

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, fonts

I am using on my Mac Machine an R piece of code that aims to plot a scatter plot.

I feel that I understood what the problem is, but I am not aware of a solution. The piece of code I am using is the following:

```
library(extrafont)
extrafont::loadfonts(device="win")
font_import() # import all your fonts
fonts() #get a list of fonts
fonttable()

ggplot(aggregate(cbind(Tax_Burden,debt_GDP) ~ cou, data=df, mean, na.rm=TRUE), aes(x=log(debt_GDP), y=log(Tax_Burden))) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Tax_Burden, size=debt_GDP))+  
  labs(color = "Tax Burden\n[% Total Revenues]", size = "Public Debt [% GDP]")+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, linetype="dashed")+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = cou), size = 2)+
  ylab("Log of Tax Burden") +
  xlab("Log of Public Debt [% GDP]") +
  theme_minimal() +
      theme(text =element_text(family="Bell MT"),
            legend.background = element_blank(),
            legend.key   = element_blank(),
            legend.text  = element_text(size = 8),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8), 
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8))
```

as far as I understood the whole problem comes the use of `Bell MT`fonts.

For example, the error I get is this:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

with the first warning being:

```
1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  no font could be found for family "Bell MT"
```

This error is removed once I drop the `Bell MT` fonts, and use the default option.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Many thanks

Comment: What is the first warning?

Comment: @NelsonGon edited the question. Please see the answer there.

Comment: What does this output? `"Bell MT" %in% fonts()`

Comment: I've found [`showtext`](https://github.com/yixuan/showtext) to be more flexible than `extrafont` if you'd want to switch packages

Comment: @NelsonGon it gives me FALSE, so these fonts are not installed, i suppose, or no ?

Comment: Is it correct to use `extrafont::loadfonts(device="win")` if you're on a Mac?

Comment: @JonSpring what's the option for mac, then? Anyways, I don't this is the main problem. Though this option maybe I should remove it. I think the main problem is that these fonts I want to use are not installed in my mac. So, maybe someone who know how I can do it, could solve this problem.

Comment: Try these suggestions: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128091/where-can-i-find-default-microsoft-fonts-calibri-cambria and probably play around with the path loadfonts uses probably using `extrafont::ttf_import`